# Wrap only text in div with text and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs with numbers, and some divs with numbers and text. If a div has numbers and text, I want to wrap the text in a span so I can change it's font size.

Looks like this:

```
<div>Word 500</div>
<div>350</div>
```

I want to use JS to make it like this:

```
<div><span>Word</span> 500</div>
<div>350</div>
```

I've tried looping through the string and checking for letters/numbers and splicing in a  around the word. But I haven't found a good solution yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the looping again, but use regex to match the word, and then replace it with the word surrounded by the wanted tags

Comment: I tried, but dont know how to get the word into the replacing string. I wont always know what the word is, no it needs to match any word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replaceWith()` jq method:

```js
$('div').contents().replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.replace(/([a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
div span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Word 500</div>
<div>350</div>
<div>wWÅÄÖåäö 600</div>
<div>50</div>
```

Comment: i was trying with javascript, can we have that one too.

Comment: @Jai that would be something like that even not checking for nodeType here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hq9drwx/

Comment: WOW! That's what i always miss `call()` method.

Comment: I have the letters å, ä and ö in some words, is there a regex for these letters aswell?

Comment: @kylmark Updated answer, i guess handling all special letters

Comment: @A.Wolff I would add a "g" modified in your Javascript solution in case of that kind of strings: "word 500 word"

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code.

It uses the `.split()` function to break entire text into string array and check each word for number.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").each(function(){
    var entireText = $(this).text();
    var allWords = entireText.split(" ");
    var updatedText = "";
    $(this).empty();
    $.each(allWords, function(i,value){
      if(isNaN(value))
        {
          updatedText+= "<span>"+value+"</span>&nbsp";
        }
      else
        {
          updatedText+= value;
        }
    });
    
    $(this).html(updatedText);
  });  
});
```

```css
span{
  color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Word 500</div>
<div>350</div>
```

Comment: @kylmark what A.Wolff has posted is the better one here.

Comment: The problem with his solution is that the site is swedish and has the letters ÅÄÖ, so finding letters a-z isnt enough. unless theres a regex for åäö aswell?

Comment: I am totally agree with @Jai... A.Wolff's answer is really smart one. I learned 2 more jQuery functions `$.contents()` and `$.replaceWith()`. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\b[A-Za-z]+\b/g, 
            function(x) {return '<span class="textClass">' + x + '</span>';
        }));
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7q7zyu8/

Comment: what is the difference/pro/con between this and A.Wolffs answer?

Comment: I was writing the response before A. Wolffs posted his, that's why I posted. Personally, I think that my answer is simpler to understand.

Comment: honestly, i dont really *understand* either, but they both work! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = '<div>Word 500</div>'.split('500');
var number = '<div>Word 500</div>'.split('500');

var name = split[0];
```

Now that you have the string parsed you can just use them, what every way you want.

Comment: Since I dont always know what the word or the number will be, this wont work.